# "Stop sync and delete data from Google" from Google Dashboard does nothing

Tags: google-chrome, google-dashboard

I've tried it on multiple computers, restarted, tried it over the course of few months, but I can't ever get it to work.  There are loads of reports on Google's forums and one in the chromium bug application, but no results.

[image: stop sync and delete data from google]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help future travelers, but I think I had too much Autofill data saved.  According to this [chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112978), the only way to get it fixed is to ask chromium people to nuke it for you.